# Filter a javascript tree without mutating the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a react project where I need to filter an array of objects without mutating the original array

```js
const array = [{
 name: 'bar',
  children: [{
   name: 'foo',
    children: [{
     name: 'baz123',
    }, {
     name: 'baz',
    }]
  }]
}, {
 name: 'shallowKey'
}, {
 name: 'abc'
}];
```

For example, I want to only filter the concerned object and its children.

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmzhjji/081q60qg/3/)

```
function filterData(data) {
  var r = data.filter(function(o) {
    if (o.children) o.children = filterData(o.children);
    return o.name.length === 3;
  })
  return r;
}
```

I tried that function from a stackoverflow question, but is there a way to use that same functionality without mutating the data. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have any prototypes or functions involved within the objects a simple way to copy is to stringify original and parse it back to object

```
var r= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).filter(...
```

Comment: saved me after 4 hours of debugging. I thought `[...data]` is doing the job and the problem is somewhere else. I was wrong!

Answer (score 4):

Array `.filter()` already creates a new array, you just need to fix the part where the `o.children` is mutated. To do that you could use `.map()` and simply copy all fields using `Object.assign()` or [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and just assign `children` as the result passed through the same filter function:

```
function filterData(data) {
  return data
    .filter(obj => obj.name.length === 3) // filter array first
    .map(obj => ({ // then re-map to new objects
      ...obj, // copy shallow fields
      children: obj.children && filterData(obj.children) // filter children
    }));
}
```

Comment: That would work, but what if the current object doesn't have a `children` property.

Comment: @aspiring_dev Then it would have to be reworked to match your data structure (as would any filter function, whether you clone it first or not). This was just based on your example. If you wanted a generalized function that traverse any object tree and apply a filter function that would be another approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a copy of your original array using a spread operator or `Object.assign()` function.

```
const arrayCopy= [...array] //spread operator
const arrayCopy = Object.assign({}, array);
```

Otherwise as Aaron suggested, using `filter()`, `map()`, `reduce()` function always returns a new array without mutating your original array.

Comment: `[...array]` will create a *shallow* copy so wouldn't solve the issue here, and `Object.assign({}, array)` would create an object not an array.